# How to flim strip vertical

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

```css
.filmstrip {
  --background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  --size: 10px;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(to right, var(--background) var(--size), transparent var(--size)),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--background) var(--size), transparent var(--size)),
    linear-gradient(to right, var(--background) var(--size), transparent var(--size)),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--background) var(--size), transparent var(--size)),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent var(--size), var(--background) var(--size));
  background-size: calc(var(--size) * 2) var(--size), calc(var(--size) * 2) var(--size), calc(var(--size) * 2) var(--size), calc(var(--size) * 2) var(--size), 100% calc(100% - var(--size) * 3);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0 var(--size), top left, 0 calc(100% - var(--size)), bottom left, 0 var(--size);
  padding: calc(var(--size) * 3) calc(var(--size) * 2.5);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="filmstrip"><h1>Stuff in the Film Strip</h1></div>
```

I did repair code

```
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

But I don't suscess

I've fixed a lot hope you guys can help me
can you help me please

Comment: How about adding `transform: rotate(90deg);`? That would probably need a bit more tweaking to get it right. Or, perhaps it's not the best solution.

Comment: How exactly do you want it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider one `conic-gradient`

```css
.filmstrip {
  --background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  --size: 10px;
  
  background:
   conic-gradient(at var(--size),var(--background) 75%,#0000 0)
   0 0/calc(100% - var(--size)) calc(2*var(--size)) padding-box;
   
  border: var(--size) solid var(--background);
  padding: calc(var(--size) * 2.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="filmstrip"><h1>Stuff in the Film Strip</h1></div>
```

And to have the initial direction we switch a few values

```css
.filmstrip {
  --background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  --size: 10px;
  
  background:
   conic-gradient(at 50% var(--size),var(--background) 75%,#0000 0)
   0 0/calc(2*var(--size)) calc(100% - var(--size)) padding-box;

  border: var(--size) solid var(--background);
  padding: calc(var(--size) * 2.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="filmstrip"><h1>Stuff in the Film Strip</h1></div>
```

Comment: How  add frame transparent middle ?